# Problem with Association on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

**View**

```
<%= form_for @product, :url => admin_products_path do |f| %>
<div>  
  <%= f.label :name %>  
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 7 %>
</div>
<%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
  <p><%= a.label "Address One" %><br />
    <%= a.text_field :address_one %></p>

  <p><%= a.label "Address Two" %><br />
    <%= a.text_field :address_two %></p>

  <p><%= a.label :city %><br />
    <%= a.text_field :city %></p>

  <p><%= a.label :postcode %><br />
    <%= a.text_field :postcode %></p>

    <p><%= a.label :country %><br />
    <%= a.select :country_id, Country.active.collect {|p| [ p.printable_name, p.id ] } %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
 def create
   @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Product was successfully created.'
      render 'show'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable    
end
```

but when save data it show issue: 
 `Address(#93165130) expected,got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#79365750)`

Please help me solved this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try if adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` solves this.

Comment: also you might need to add `attr_accessible :address_attributes` to the `Product` model.

Answer (score 0):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

if not work then try also adding along with accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

```
attr_accessor :address
```